# What are the same common fields between crypto-config.yaml、configtx.yaml and docker-compose.yaml files

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to know the corresponding **field** between crypto-config.yaml、configtx.yaml and docker-compose.yaml files.
In the above three files , which **common fields** must be the same ,please point out the same common fields,

It is very important to make the fabric network works and find out the issues.

Answer (score 1):

The *configtx.yaml* file and the *dockcer-compose.yaml* file are related by the **MSP identificator**. In the *configtx.yaml*, you define for each organization by the `ID` field; In the *docker-compose.yaml* you define it for each container by the `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` field for the Peers and the `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID` field for the Orderers.

On the other hand, the **CN** of the certificates that you use to connect among different nodes has to be related to the host of each one. So you have to define the *crypto-config.yaml* file according to that. In that file, you define the `domain` and the `hostname` for each node. This info has to be related with the definition of each container that you do on the *docker-compose.yaml* file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,excellent !  Could you describe  second paragraph answer detaily? what relationship using the detail fields like the first paragrah ? And are there any other relationship among this three files?

Comment: Hi! When you connect to a host in a secure way, you should have its public key. The connection will be successful, if the CN of that public key and the host are the same. On ther other hand, about your last question, I think that there isn't any relationship among this three files.

Comment: I can understand your meaning .I just want to know  which **fields** in the which files related to the **CN**  of the certificates except for crypto-config.yaml? Thank you!